# rmiregistry не запускается на localhost

Tags: java, linux, rmi

Есть специализированное приложение на java, которое не запускается под ubuntu.
При запуске выдает, что не может соединится с rmiregistry

```
cannot bind to existing RMI Registry!
RemoteExeption occurred in server thead: nested exception is: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments;
nested exception is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer.
```

В момент работы приложения rmiregistry запускается на IPv6:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2007/dropbox        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17603         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2007/dropbox        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2007/dropbox        
tcp6       0      0 :::35777                :::*                    LISTEN      7071/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::37639                :::*                    LISTEN      7044/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::1099                 :::*                    LISTEN      7102/rmiregistry    
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::1716                 :::*                    LISTEN      1969/kdeconnectd    
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::17500                :::*                    LISTEN      2007/dropbox
```

/etc/hosts выглядит так:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.1.60    UX370UAR

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

При ручном запуске rmiregistry он также запускается на IPv6, но приложение  выдает другую ошибку:

```
RMI Registry monitoring may not be available. This may happen when RMI Registry
* started from another third-party application;
* manually or automatically stopped.
Please check your condition
```

Ниже лог приложения, когда rmiregistry запускает само приложение:

```
@ - 2018-07-22 11:54:48,461 - INFO - c.a.w.n.NetoApplication - 
******************************************
* NEtO starts @ 2018-07-22 11:54:48,460 *
****************************************** - 
@ - 2018-07-22 11:54:48,464 - INFO - c.a.i.w.w.u.c.ConfigurationParameters - Configuration file opened. - 
@ - 2018-07-22 11:54:48,465 - INFO - c.a.i.w.w.u.c.ConfigurationParameters - Configuration file loaded. - 
@ - 2018-07-22 11:54:48,465 - INFO - c.a.i.w.w.u.c.PathConfiguration - JAVA path= /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_45 - 
@ - 2018-07-22 11:54:48,465 - INFO - c.a.i.w.w.u.c.PathConfiguration - Jusm path= /home/igor/9500/NETO - 
NEtO_Server_1532246088465@ - 2018-07-22 11:54:48,466 - INFO - c.a.i.w.w.u.c.ConfigurationParameters - Configuration ready. - 
NEtO_Server_1532246088465@ - 2018-07-22 11:54:48,466 - INFO - c.a.i.w.w.u.c.ConfigurationParameters - Configuration file closed. - 
NEtO_Server_1532246088465@ - 2018-07-22 11:54:49,086 - INFO - c.a.w.n.NetoApplication - neto.mode=  - 
NEtO_Server_1532246088465@ - 2018-07-22 11:54:49,086 - INFO - c.a.w.n.NetoApplication - NEtO starts with normal mode - 
NEtO_Server_1532246088465@ - 2018-07-22 11:54:54,136 - INFO - c.a.w.c.u.HostAddr - Addresses to use for this Host are: IPv4: 192.168.1.60 - IPv6: null - 
NEtO_Server_1532246088465@ - 2018-07-22 11:54:54,235 - ERROR - c.a.w.c.r.Server - RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer - java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.retrieveAndBindRegistry(Server.java:355)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.activateServer(Server.java:80)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.<init>(Server.java:61)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.<init>(Server.java:74)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.controllers.rmi.RmiData.getRmiServer(RmiData.java:128)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.controllers.rmi.RmiController.<init>(RmiController.java:68)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.Controllers.<init>(Controllers.java:52)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.NetoApplication.startUp(NetoApplication.java:151)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.NetoApplication.main(NetoApplication.java:101)
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyInterfaces(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 common frames omitted

NEtO_Server_1532246088465@ - 2018-07-22 11:54:54,236 - ERROR - c.a.w.c.r.Server - RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer - java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.retrieveAndBindRegistry(Server.java:355)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.activateServer(Server.java:80)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.<init>(Server.java:61)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.<init>(Server.java:74)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.controllers.rmi.RmiData.getRmiServer(RmiData.java:128)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.controllers.rmi.RmiController.<init>(RmiController.java:68)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.Controllers.<init>(Controllers.java:52)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.NetoApplication.startUp(NetoApplication.java:151)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.NetoApplication.main(NetoApplication.java:101)
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyInterfaces(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 common frames omitted

NEtO_Server_1532246088465@ - 2018-07-22 11:54:54,236 - ERROR - c.a.w.n.m.c.r.RmiData - First connection attempt not good: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer - java.rmi.RemoteException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.activateServer(Server.java:84)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.<init>(Server.java:61)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.<init>(Server.java:74)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.controllers.rmi.RmiData.getRmiServer(RmiData.java:128)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.controllers.rmi.RmiController.<init>(RmiController.java:68)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.Controllers.<init>(Controllers.java:52)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.NetoApplication.startUp(NetoApplication.java:151)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.NetoApplication.main(NetoApplication.java:101)

NEtO_Server_1532246088465@ - 2018-07-22 11:54:59,263 - ERROR - c.a.w.c.r.Server - RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer - java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.retrieveAndBindRegistry(Server.java:355)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.activateServer(Server.java:80)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.<init>(Server.java:61)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.<init>(Server.java:74)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.controllers.rmi.RmiData.getRmiServer(RmiData.java:141)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.controllers.rmi.RmiController.<init>(RmiController.java:68)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.Controllers.<init>(Controllers.java:52)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.NetoApplication.startUp(NetoApplication.java:151)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.NetoApplication.main(NetoApplication.java:101)
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyInterfaces(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 common frames omitted

NEtO_Server_1532246088465@ - 2018-07-22 11:54:59,264 - ERROR - c.a.w.c.r.Server - RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer - java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.retrieveAndBindRegistry(Server.java:355)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.activateServer(Server.java:80)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.<init>(Server.java:61)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.<init>(Server.java:74)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.controllers.rmi.RmiData.getRmiServer(RmiData.java:141)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.controllers.rmi.RmiController.<init>(RmiController.java:68)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.Controllers.<init>(Controllers.java:52)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.NetoApplication.startUp(NetoApplication.java:151)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.NetoApplication.main(NetoApplication.java:101)
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyInterfaces(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 common frames omitted

NEtO_Server_1532246088465@ - 2018-07-22 11:54:59,264 - ERROR - c.a.w.n.m.c.r.RmiData - Second connection attempt not good: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer then shutdown! - java.rmi.RemoteException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.activateServer(Server.java:84)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.<init>(Server.java:61)
    at com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.Server.<init>(Server.java:74)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.controllers.rmi.RmiData.getRmiServer(RmiData.java:141)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.controllers.rmi.RmiController.<init>(RmiController.java:68)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.Controllers.<init>(Controllers.java:52)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.NetoApplication.startUp(NetoApplication.java:151)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.NetoApplication.main(NetoApplication.java:101)

NEtO_Server_1532246088465@ - 2018-07-22 11:55:16,775 - WARN - c.a.w.n.m.c.r.RmiData - Removing NEtO_Server_1532246088465 from RMI Registry. - 
NEtO_Server_1532246088465@ - 2018-07-22 11:55:16,793 - ERROR - c.a.w.n.m.c.r.RmiData - NEtO_Server_1532246088465 - java.rmi.NotBoundException: NEtO_Server_1532246088465
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.unbind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.unbind(Unknown Source)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.controllers.rmi.RmiData.removeFromRmiRegistry(RmiData.java:177)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.controllers.rmi.RmiData.getRmiServer(RmiData.java:149)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.controllers.rmi.RmiController.<init>(RmiController.java:68)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.mvc.Controllers.<init>(Controllers.java:52)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.NetoApplication.startUp(NetoApplication.java:151)
    at com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.NetoApplication.main(NetoApplication.java:101)
```

java 1.6:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

  Выбор   Путь                                        Приор Состояние
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      автоматический режим
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      ручной режим
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java                1         ручной режим
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_45/                        1         ручной режим
* 4            /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_45/bin/java                1         ручной режим


 Выбор   Путь                                               Приор Состояние
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/rmiregistry   1081      автоматический режим
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/rmiregistry   1081      ручной режим
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/rmiregistry                1         ручной режим
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_45/bin/rmiregistry                1         ручной режим
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что смотреть или куда копать?

Comment: Чукча не читатель? Он же вам пишет, что не может найти класс `com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer`. Ну так добавьте её в приложение

Comment: объясните, пжл, как это сделать. Это готовое приложение. Под windows оно запускается.

Comment: Найти jar библиотеку с классом `com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer` и докинуть в каталог с библиотеками приложения

Comment: Приложение запускается так: 
java -Djava.security.policy=java.policy -Dlogback.configurationFile=conf/Logback_NEtO.xml -classpath lib/neto.jar:lib/alu_LAF_2.0.jar:lib/aneto_utils.jar:lib/rlo_data.jar:lib/rmicomm-ng.jar:lib/roger.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.7.1.jar:lib/snmp4j-1.11.3.jar:lib/synthetica.jar:.:res:lib/jlfgr-1_0.jar:lib/logback-classic-1.0.7.jar:lib/logback-core-1.0.7.jar:lib/CNM-CommonIcons_PNG.zip com.alcatel_lucent.wtd.neto.NetoApplication $1 $2 $3 $4 $5
com.alcatel.wtd.common.rmicomm.IServer находится в lib/rmicomm-ng.jar. Это я смотрю через архив.
сорри, что сплошным тектом.

Comment: может быть проблема из-за относительности пути. Можете попробовать указать абсолютный путь до библиотеки `rmicomm-ng.jar`

Comment: увы, не помогло. И для rmicomm-ng.jar полный путь указал и для всех jar.